# How to stop PHP file exection with exec

Tags: php, python-2.7

I have written several scripts to achieve a **Marquee effect**.

my idea is that the php script take charge of executing,and the py script handle the controll flow.

My file.php:

```
<?php
exec(" sudo python /var/www/html/3ledblink.py");
?>
```

My file.py I use to loop (While)

```
          while True:

        # Red for 7 seconds
                trafficState(1,0,0)
                time.sleep(7)

       # Green for 5 seconds
                trafficState(0,1,0)
                time.sleep(5)

        # Yellow for 2 seconds
                trafficState(0,0,1)
                time.sleep(2)
```

And now I  can't to stop it.
Please, Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running php file in a terminal just press `ctrl+c` to terminate it

Comment: Yes, I did so. And ok

Comment: But, I want to stop when  it is running in php

Comment: If you want to stop it from php then you should have some necessary condition in the php code to stop it. From necessary condition I mean it can be time interval or some specific value

Comment: Thanks you, But What is necessary condition?
I don't know. You can help me.
:)

Comment: when do you want to stop it?

Comment: @VõThịHoàiThu I'm very sorry but I'm not able to get you what you are talking about. Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: I use to 2 submit on php
Submit1: LED blink
Submit2: Reset or do something else.
I want to click submit 1 it working normally, and click submit2 it will do something else.

Comment: Sorry, I first used

Comment: Again we are back to square one. So when do you want to stop the python execution?

Comment: When I press submit2 then stopped submit1

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what to say so that you know what I mean. I'm very trying for you to understand. Is there anything pleasant you remind me, please.

Comment: @VõThịHoàiThu do not feel sorry. I'll try my best. Can you please share that code where you've added `submit1` and `submit2` functionality?

Comment: Yes, You wait for me a minutes

Comment: Append it with your Question

Comment: what is your `reset.py` file doing?

Comment: It cleanup GPIO.

Comment: And, it off LEDs

Comment: But it is not going to stop the execution. For this create a boolean variable and use that variable in while expression and make false when you click reset. it will stop the execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't able to stop `exec` process Runtime using PHP.

If you want to stop the infinite exec command process then you should restart your apache server. Because you aren't able to stop the execution of the command once fire using PHP.

Comment: Thanks you.
I don't know how to do it  :(

Comment: Hi, what is the solution you found please share in this thread, it's helpful for other users which face this kind of issue in future.

Comment: yes, :))
I have do:
chmod 777 file.py and 
chown $USER:SUER file.py
After exec in php

Comment: After changing the file permission you able to stop the exec command after firing? It's so strange

Comment: Actually someone helped me
He did it